# How to let hazelcast fail if the cluster name does not match?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast based application, which passes a specific set of ips and ports to hazelcast.

How can I make hazelcast fail, if one of those sockets belongs to a cluster with a different name?

---

As example, I want those setups to fail fast:

```
node1 has ip1, is configured to form a cluster called "hello" with ip2
node2 has ip2, is configured to form a cluster called "world" with ip1
```

Currently this only yields a log message:

```
WARN: Node could not join cluster at node: [ip1]:9003 Cause: the target cluster has a different group-name
```

But I want hazelcast to fail in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The two nodes should build independent clusters, as the names do not match. This is actually intended design as you might want to start multiple clusters in the same multicast zone. If they join this would be a bug.

What I guess you're looking for, the second node that comes up to fast-fail if it cannot join the existing cluster. This is the case if the cluster-name (group-name) is identical but the password doesn't match. Now the second node will fail to join and stops operation.

Comment: It does not work. Connecting with wrong credentials only causes another log message: `Received auth from Connection[id=41, /192.168.33.11:9003->/192.168.33.12:37078, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE] with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='8cf96bb9-a3e7-4488-9547-e14d2a475557', ownerUuid='73884d75-b751-43a0-b752-e0bc3bb17d44'} , authentication failed` (in the logs of all members)

Comment: As mentioned group-password makes it fail. I guess it retries 3 times before it gives up.

Comment: That is not the case anymore since version 3.8.2. See the note at http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#creating-cluster-groups

Comment: Ok yeah, fair enough. Thanks for the clarification @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource :)